# Proving Egorov's Theorem with Dini's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Egorov's theorem states: let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions that converges pointwise to a measurable function $f$ on domain $E$ with $m(E)<\infty$ then there exists $E_0\subset E$ such that the $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $E_0$ and $m(E \setminus E_0)<\epsilon$

My proof attempt using Dini's theorem: By theorem 3.4 in *Real Analysis by Stein & Shakarchi* if $E$ is measurable, which it is in above case, there exists a compact set $K \subset E$ with $m(E \setminus K)<\epsilon$. The proof of this is pretty simple it involves taking an inner approximation of $E$ by a closed set and then intersecting that closed set by an arbitrarily large closed, bounded ball.

Let $E_0=K$, since $K$ is compact and the $f_n$ converge pointwise on all of $K$ we can invoke Dini's theorem to get uniform convergence on $K$ if we can guarantee the $f_n$ are monotonic. Is there any way the sequence can be manipulated so we can guarantee they are monotonic? Is all the effort in proving Egorov's theorem really about dealing with non-monotic sequences?

Comment: Doesn't Dini's theorem require continuity of both the $f_n$ and $f$?  You could get a monotonic sequence by considering, e.g. $\sup_{k \geq n} |f_k(x) - f(x)|,$ but since we don't know anything about continuity, I don't see how Dini would be used (unless you're talking about a different theorem, in which case, can you state Dini's theorem for us?)